# gulp task doesn't output css files

Tags: css, sass, gulp

guys

I'm pretty new in gulp, so please help. Can't understand why the following code executes without errors but doesn't output css files.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return sass('sass/*.scss', { style: 'expanded' })
    .on('error', function (err) {
      console.error('Error!', err.message);
    })
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(minifycss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});
```

Comment: You may want to change `.pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))` to `.pipe(rename({suffix: '.min.css'}))`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, seems issue was related with line

```
return sass('sass/*.scss', { style: 'expanded' })
```

It should look like

```
return sass('sass', { style: 'expanded' })
```

As mentioned in the [`gulp-ruby-sass` docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ruby-sass#important):

> gulp-ruby-sass doesn't support globs yet, only single files or directories. Just like Sass.